# Django: What to do when I need a remote access to ORM

Tags: django

Basically, I have two django servers (django v 1.2):

Server 1 has a bunch of models, local database, and remote database access to ModelA in Server 2.
Server 2 has ModelA

I want to use ModelA.objects.get() and django ORM API in Server 1 for ModelA. Am I supposed to just duplicate models.py from Server 2 to Server 1? By just copying models.py over, I can use the ORM methods and trust the database routers that I set up to not do weird stuff when they syncdb.

This seems to be good enough right? I don't see any reason to use django-piston or those other restful API packages because in those cases, I have to still add all the extra code to recognize the model. Main reason I even dove into looking at the API packages is because I was wondering if there was a clean way of giving ORM access without duplicating the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying the code is pretty common.  You can configure your settings to point to whatever database server you want.

As an app grows it is common to have to add webservers.  One way this can be done is to copy your code base to another machine and run it behind a reverse proxy.

This means the exact same code is running on more than one machine, sharing a database backend.

Django provides an 'app' structure which you might want to look at.  You can package an app and distribute it to another projecct.

Comment: yeah, i thought as much. i just made a new app for the model im sharing and have the database router set up for that. thanks